# Python: why not (a, b, c) = (*x, 3)

Tags: python

So apparently I can't do this in Python (2.7):

```
x = (1, 2,)
(a, b, c) = (*x, 3)
```

It made sense in my head, but well... I could create a function:

```
make_tuple = lambda *elements: tuple(elements)
```

then I can do

```
(c, a, b) = make_tuple(3, *x)
```

but not, for example

```
(a, b, c) = make_tuple(*x, 3)
(a, b, c, d) = make_tuple(*x, *x)
y = [3, 4]
(a, b, c, d) = (*x, *y,)
```

So what I am asking is

1. is there a reason for not allowing this? (the first thing)
2. what is the closest thing that does work?

My current guess for #2:

```
(a, b, c) = x + (3,)
(a, b, c, d) = x + x
(a, b, c, d) = x + tuple(y)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In response to question 1, read the [PEP 448](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/) and [bug 2292](http://bugs.python.org/issue2292). Also interesting is the discussion in the [mailing list](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2005-October/057163.html). In resume what you want should be allowed in Python 3.4. For question 2 see the other solutions.

Comment: Interesting, and great addition!

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget itertools. It's usually more readable as things get more complex

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> a,b,c = chain(x, (3,))
>>> a,b,c,d = chain(x, x)
>>> a,b,c,d = chain(x, y)
```

Comment: Probably the best alternative, although it's a shame that 3 still needs to be made into a tuple...

Comment: @Mark, there is no builtin "flatten", but many of the flatten recipies on SO would let you say `a, b, c = flatten((x, 3))`. You could support `flatten(x, 3)` without too much extra work.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do in Python 2.7 is:

```
(a, b), c = x, 3
```

Comment: Indeed a nice solution in this case, though too bad it can't create one tuple